# For an angle, what does it mean to be bounded away 90 degrees?

Tags: numerical-optimization

Nocedal and Wright, in their book Numerical Optimization, just above (3.17), use this wording:

> ...the angle $\theta_k$ is bounded away from $90^\circ$,...

what does this mean?

Comment: Something that is bounded is limited in some way. A function that is bounded upwards can not take infinitely large values. Something that is bounded away from something else can not get arbitrary close to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means: there exists some $\phi>0$ such that $|\theta-90|>\phi$.